# Redirect users to a page not found when they click on a css/js file from view source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Is it possible to let users redirect to a "page not found" when they click a css/js from the view source of their browser. Or maybe something like this 
[image]

My goal for this is not let the user see the content of my files so that they will have no idea what plugins I am using.

I am using wordpress and my client doesn't want me to let his users see what plugins he is using. I already found a plugin called http://codecanyon.net/item/hide-my-wp-no-one-can-know-you-use-wordpress/4177158
but the probleme with that plugin is that when users try to view source their browser, they will see the styles.css or other js files, and in those files, that content usually has its plugin name.

Some of you might suggest to not write the name of the plugin on those css/js files, but I don't have control on that.

So any ideas or suggestions on how to come up with this solution will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks! :)

Comment: You could try to rename the wordpress plugins and minify the JS and the CSS files.

Comment: You could also try to encode the js files. You can use http://www.jsobfuscate.com/

Comment: @NETCreator so it's like I will create a code that would minify all js/css in my site? Though I don't have a control on the js/css of the other plugins, I'll just create a plugin that would do all of those?

Comment: it will anyway not work. You always can decode them back. The idea of your public files is that anyone who wants can access it - does not matter if it is a browser client or whoever else.